# Drawing a line with JTextField values, what do I do wrong?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jtextfield, paintcomponent

I need some help with my code. I would like to draw a line and afterwords some other shapes. I thought a line would be a good start. I am trying to get the x and y values out of a textField, and it works. Unfortunately the line itself does not print/paint itself. What do I do wrong and how can I make the line appear?

```
package zadanie;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    GraphicsClass graph = new GraphicsClass();
    JTextField textField1;
    JTextField textField2;
    JTextField textField3;
    JTextField textField4;
    
    public MyFrame() {
        
        textField1 = new JTextField(20);
        textField1.setBounds(10,20,30,20);
        textField1.addActionListener(this);
        
        textField2 = new JTextField(20);
        textField2.setBounds(50,20,30,20);
        textField2.addActionListener(this);
        
        textField3 = new JTextField(20);
        textField3.setBounds(10,50,30,20);
        textField3.addActionListener(this);
        
        textField4 = new JTextField(20);
        textField4.setBounds(50,50,30,20);
        textField4.addActionListener(this);
        
        graph.drawButton = new JButton("Click Me!");
        graph.drawButton.setBounds(0,80,100,40);
        graph.drawButton.addActionListener(this);
        
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(textField1);
        this.add(textField2);
        this.add(textField3);
        this.add(textField4);
        this.add(graph.drawButton);
        this.add(graph);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        int x1 = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
        int x2 = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
        int y1 = Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText());
        int y2 = Integer.parseInt(textField4.getText());

        System.out.println(x1);
        System.out.println(x2);
        System.out.println(y1);
        System.out.println(y2);
        
        graph.setLine(getGraphics(), x1, y1, x2, y2);
        
    }
}
```

```
package zadanie;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsClass extends JPanel{
    
//  MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    
    JButton drawButton = new JButton();
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2D.drawLine(50, 50, 200, 300);
        
        
        
    }

    void setLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend starting with [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) to get a better understanding how the paint system works. I'd also recommend looking at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: FYI - You should never call `getGraphics` - this is not how custom painting works

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) For integer values, the user would typically prefer to be offered a `JSpinner`.